# JScript - Accessing Variable Between Functions

Tags: javascript

First post here with what's likely an extremely basic JavaScript question. I have the following code:

```
var decklist = [];

function CreateDeck() {
   var deckform = document.getElementById("txtar_decklist").value.split('\n');
   var stats = [];
   for (var n = 0; n < deckform.length; n++){
       if (deckform[n] != ""){
           stats = deckform[n].split(',');
           for (var x = 0; x < parseInt(stats[0],10); x++){
               decklist.push({Name:     stats[1],
                              Color:    stats[2], 
                              Type:     stats[3],
                              Subtype:  stats[4], 
                              Level:    stats[5],
                              Attack:   stats[6],
                              Defense:  stats[7],
                              Drawn:    false});
            }
        }
    }
};

function DrawCard() {
    var randomcard = 0;
    var carddrawn = false;
    while (carddrawn == false){
        randomcard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * decklist.length + 1)) - 1;
        if (decklist[randomcard].Drawn == false){
            alert(JSON.stringify(decklist[randomcard]));
            decklist[randomcard].Drawn = true;
            carddrawn = true;
        }
    }
};
```

In my webpage, a user inserts a decklist and an array of objects is created to store the stats/fields of each card. I have a second button that attempts to "draw" a card with a property of .Drawn = false, then immediately assigns a true value to that property to prevent the user from drawing that same card again.

I can't seem to figure out how to make my variable "shared" between these two functions. I've tried what I think is a global variable declaration as shown above, as well as trying my hand at creating a module for pseudo-global use. Would anyone mind showing me what I'm doing wrong?

Oh, and if my variable declaration is in fact fine for what I'm doing and the issue lies in the second function, please let me know.

My background is in VB.Net (also VBScript + VBA) and SQL. Have taken very basic JavaScript and HTML classes in college, but didn't pursue them enough once the classes were over to retain much of what I learned.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not use function composition, and pass arguments around, like `drawCard(createDeck(deckForm))`?

Comment: Currently its a global variable, so it is shared across function. Can you tell us what is the issue?

Comment: Is it possible this has anything to do with the first function being called from a button in a form?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scope problem. If you're using require and each function resides in it's own file, or the decklist variable is being access by some other function using require, then the desklist var will be out of scope.

One solution might be to set decklist to the window scope as:

```
window.decklist = [];
```

That'll ensure decklist is accessible from anything on the page. Note that you MAY have to change any of your references to decklist in your functions to use window.decklist as well.

Comment: He mentioned using a module, so I'm assuming here.

Comment: Point is even if it is wrapped inside a module, its still shareable across both function

Comment: Thanks for the discussion so far. Even with setting the variable to the window scope, it still didn't work. It's worth noting that when the first function, CreateDeck(), contained a loop to alert through each object in the array, that worked perfectly fine. But for some reason the second function isn't doing anything at all. I just assumed it was a scope problem in my variable, but maybe it's something else.

Comment: @TylerG do you get any alert?

Comment: The second function isn't creating an alert for some reason.

Comment: @TylerG my bet is your random number is going out of bound. Try `Math.floor(math.random()*1000) % decklist.length`.